# rows getting pushed down by long column in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, formatting

I'm trying to make a layout like this using bootstrap.

[image: desired layout]

However, I keep getting this

[image: what i actually get]

Does anyone know how to prevent the second row from being pushed down by the large column?

Here is a skeleton of my HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 about">
                <img >
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 resume">
                <img >
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 websites">
                <img >
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 waterfall">
                <img >
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 middlebox">
                <p id="middletext"><strong></strong><br></p>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

and here is the corresponding CSS:

```
.col-xs-3{
    height: 33vh;
    margin-bottom: 3vh;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.col-xs-3.resume{
    margin-top: 3vh;
}

.col-xs-3.websites{
    height: 60vh;
    margin-top: 3vh;
}

.col-xs-6{
    height: 33vh;
    margin-bottom: 3vh;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.col-xs-6.about{
    margin-top: 3vh;
}
```

Comment: share some of your code.

Comment: Nesting is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that I can think of is to use one div as parent for the first 2 columns:

html:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-sm-9" >
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 about">
                    <img >
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 resume">
                    <img >
                </div>                
                <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 waterfall">
                    <img >
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 middlebox">
                    <p id="middletext"><strong></strong><br></p>
                </div>                
            </div>            
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 websites">
                <img >
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.col-xs-4{
    height: 33vh;
    margin-bottom: 3vh;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.resume{
    margin-top: 3vh;
}

.websites{
    height: 68vh;
    margin-top: 3vh;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.col-xs-8{
    height: 33vh;
    margin-bottom: 3vh;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.col-xs-8.about{
    margin-top: 3vh;
}
```

Comment: why do you use column widths of 8 and 4 inside the parent div with width 9? does it create a subgrid that still has 12 columns when you nest the rows?

Comment: Yes, the width of parent div is a grid with 12 columns, I use 8 and 4 to keep the ratio of your previous 6 and 3 div

Comment: thanks a lot man! just one more question though. i took all the content out of the divs and styled it so that only borders are displayed. I was trying to recreate the pictures in my question above to make sure the layout was right. Now all of the box are overlapping each other in the top row and not responding to my attempts to move them.

Comment: you mean you remove all the img, text inside each div like this: http://jsfiddle.net/c383Y/ ? It seems ok for me

Comment: thanks for your help. i probably just made a dumb mistake somewhere.

Comment: What if you need to order the differents divs in a smaller resolution ?
Order works when all divs are on the same level.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for this sort of no-gaps layout is to use something like [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com), although it's probably overkill if your actual layout is as simple as your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the 4 left smaller divs in their own two columns.

So it's still 3 columns, but instead of 2 rows it would be just 1 row.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).